# Proper use of Try

Tags: python, casting, try-catch

The problem I am having is I don't know if there is a better way of telling if a string can be converted to int in python.

```
try: 
  tempScores = int(tempScores)
except ValueError:
  tempScores = 10
```

Comment: That's the way. (Don't believe the people who tell you to use `isdigit` - that's a test for digit characters, so it fails on stuff like `'-1'`.)

Comment: Are there any problems with the code you have posted?

Comment: the code works I just wanted to know if there was a different way to tell if the string could be an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. I would only use underscores in naming, and singular (since it is one score, not many), per Python conventions: `temp_score`.

Example:

```
for temp_score in [1, '2', '3e2', '4a', 'b5']:
    try:
        temp_score = int(temp_score)
    except ValueError:
        temp_score = 10
    print(temp_score)
```

Output:

```
1
2
10
10
10
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[Python docs: Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)
[Python docs: `TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)
[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code: Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45)

Comment: Another best-practice I'd suggest would be assigning the converted value to a different name.  That makes it possible for a static typechecker (e.g. `mypy`) to keep track of which is which and alert you if you've forgotten to do a conversion.